# Postgresql: Error missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql

I have a query and I keep getting this a 'missing FROM-clase entry for table e, rx.rootentityid = rh.entityid1 AND rh.schoolid =  e.schoolid'.
can anyone see the error in my code. My postgresql knowledge is very limited.

```
SELECT
        eh.entityid1, eh.entityname1, eh.entityid2, eh.entityname2, 
        eh.entityid3, eh.entityname3, eh.entityid4, eh.entityname4, 
        eh.entityid5, eh.entityname5, eh.entityid6, eh.entityname6, 
        eh.entityid7, eh.entityname7, eh.schoolentityid, eh.schoolid, 
        eh.emiscode, eh.schoolname, rh.entityid1 AS reportentityid1,
        rh.entityname1 AS reportentityname1, rh.entityid2 AS reportentityid2,
        rh.entityname2 AS reportentityname2
        FROM dbo.vwentityhierarchyname 
        JOIN dbo.entity AS eh
            ON vwentityhierarchyname.entityid1 = eh.entityid AND eh.entitytypeid = 1 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT
            hd.rootentityid
            FROM dbo.hierarchydefinition AS hd
            JOIN dbo.entity AS e
                ON hd.rootentityid = e.entityid 
            WHERE hd.relatedrootentityid = e.entityid AND hd.entitytypeid = 7 AND LOWER(e.name) SIMILAR TO LOWER('%Report Regions%')) AS rx
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vwentityhierarchyname AS rh
            ON rx.rootentityid = rh.entityid1 AND rh.schoolid =  e.schoolid
        WHERE eh.schoolid = par_SchoolID
        ORDER BY eh.entityid1 DESC NULLS FIRST
        LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: "e" is defined within your subquery and thus not available outside the subquery. This subquery also doesn't return a schoolid

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens . Does the trick

Answer (score 2):

The error "missing FROM-clause entry for table" in PostgreSQL usually occurs when you're referencing a table or column in your SQL query, but PostgreSQL can't find it in the FROM clause. This often happens when you are using aliases or referencing a table that is not part of the main query.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate the issue:

```
SELECT users.id, orders.order_date
FROM users
JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
WHERE orders.status = 'completed';
```

In this example, if the orders table has a column named status, the query should work fine. However, if the orders table does not have a status column, or if it's in a different schema, PostgreSQL might throw the "missing FROM-clause entry" error.

To resolve this issue:

Check Your Table and Column Names:
Ensure that the table and column names in your query are correct. Verify that the columns you are referencing actually exist in the specified tables.

Use Table Aliases:
If you are using aliases for your tables, make sure to reference the alias in your SELECT and WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT u.id, o.order_date
FROM users u
JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
WHERE o.status = 'completed';
```

Check Subqueries:
If you are using subqueries, make sure they are returning the expected columns and that they are aliased correctly.

Use Schema Qualifiers:
If your tables are in different schemas, make sure to qualify the table names with the schema:

```
SELECT users.id, my_schema.orders.order_date
FROM users
JOIN my_schema.orders ON users.id = my_schema.orders.user_id
WHERE my_schema.orders.status = 'completed';
```

If you can provide the specific SQL query that is causing the issue, I can help you pinpoint the problem more accurately.